# CakePHP: Multiple Model in Controller Action:add

Tags: database, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I just started with CakePHP recently. The framework make things easy, but today I just find myself a new question.

If a `Project` model has an `image`, it would be accessible somewhere like `$this->data['Project']['image']`. Since there's only 1 image to 1 project, it can be a field in the Project table itself.

But what about if `Project` has a collection of `images`? Wouldn't it be another table say `Gallery`? Then we're talking about two Model here.

For the previous case, image can easily be uploaded in `project/add`, storing the filename into `projects`.`image`. Things happen in Project Model, and Project Controller.

Now how's the *cake* way to do it when adding a `Project` with a `Gallery`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to read your question, are you asking for the DB design or the CakePHP associations? However, assuming your project has just one gallery it would be a hasOne association, the required database fields would this

```
Project.id -> Gallery.project_id
```

The association in the project model would be:

```
$hasOne = ['Gallery' => ['foreignKey' => 'project_id']];
```

The association in the gallery model would be:

```
$belongsTo = ['Project' => ['foreignKey' => 'project_id']];
```

You don't need to declare them as long as your fields follow the naming conventions of the framework, cake will detect the right fields then automatically for you.

> But what about if Project has a collection of images? Wouldn't it be another table say Gallery? Then we're talking about two Model here.

There is no "better" way, IMHO it depends on what you need and want. In theory you can do this as well in the project model:

```
$hasMany= ['Image' => ['foreignKey' => 'project_id']];
```

[Read this section](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html), the whole section, of the official manual, it describes in detail how tables are linked together.

There is just one recommendation: I would never store file information inside another table but *always* associate my data with a files or images table. The files should not be stored as blob inside the DB as well. You can check [this plugin](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage) and it's documentation for a longer explanation.

Also, when you just started with CakePHP, why are you using the old 2.x version of the framework when there is already 3.0? I would go for 3.0 because it's a little different to the 2.x branch. If you have to switch from 2 to 3 later you'll have to learn again some things.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I thought `./cake bake` was so powerful and if it didn't bake something similar to what I want then I might have been wrong somewhere. Indeed I didn't read through the Models Association section.

And why the old 2.x Cakephp? Simply because the company I work for hasn't migrate to 3.0 yet.

Once again thanks for the recommendation.